# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: redis

I have coding like this

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();

client.on("connect", function() {
  console.log("You are now connected");
});

client.set("student", "Laylaa", function(err, reply) {
  console.log(reply);
});
```

but there is an error like this..

events.js:291
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1145:16)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
at RedisClient.on_error (E:\TEKNIK INFORMATIKA\Latihan redis\node_modules\redis\index.js:341:14)
at Socket. (E:\TEKNIK INFORMATIKA\Latihan redis\node_modules\redis\index.js:222:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 6379
}

is there a solution? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a Redis server instance running on localhost at port 6379?

Answer (score 4):

You need to first start the redis server by executing:

```
redis-server
```

in a terminal, after redis has been installed and before launching the Node.js client.

You could also add a script to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "redis": "redis-server"
}
```

and run:

```
npm run redis
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux Ubuntu you’ll need to run

> sudo apt-get install redis-server

and Redis will automatically be up and running.Once it’s started, Redis listens on port 6379

.